# Why would a key:value pair not be added to a Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

What could be reasons for this code not to add to the dictionary(assume that it is going into the `else` block):

```
if dup_agent_log.modify_stamp > merge_agent_log.modify_stamp:
    merge_agent_log.set_status_log(dup_agent_log.status, None, dup_agent_log.agents_id, dup_agent_log.source, dup_agent_log.status_type)
else:
    print merge_agent_log.data # {}
    now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    merge_agent_log.data[now] = [{"status": dup_agent_log.status, "change_agent": dup_agent_log.change_agent, "source": dup_agent_log.source}]
    print "after", merge_agent_log.data # after {}

transaction.savepoint()
```

The `AgentStatusLog()` class(model):

```
class AgentStatusLog(Base):
__tablename__ = "agent_status_log"
id = Column(
    Integer,
    Sequence("agent_status_log_id", optional=True),
    primary_key=True
)
status_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(StatusLookup.id))
_status = relationship(StatusLookup, uselist=False)
status = Column(Unicode(100), index=True)
previous_status = Column(Unicode(50), index=True)
effective_stamp = Column(DateTime, index=True)
modify_stamp = Column(DateTime, index=True)
agents_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Agents.id))
agent = relationship(Agents, primaryjoin=Agents.id == agents_id, uselist=False)
_data = Column("data", Unicode(2048))
status_type = Column(Unicode(40), index=True)
change_agents_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Agents.id))
change_agent = relationship(Agents, primaryjoin=Agents.id == change_agents_id, uselist=False)
source = Column(Unicode(100), index=True)


@property
def data(self):
    if not self._data:
        return {}
    return json.loads(self._data)

@data.setter
def data(self, value):
    self._data = json.dumps(value)

def set_data(self, field, value):
    data = self.data
    data[field] = value
    self.data = data

def get_data(self):
    if not self._data:
        return {}
    return json.loads(self._data)

def unset_data(self, field):
    data = self.get_data()
    if field in data:
        del data[field]
        self.data = data

@classmethod
def by_id(cls, id):
    return Session.query(cls).filter(cls.id == id).first()

@classmethod
def by_agents_id(cls, aid):
    return Session.query(cls).filter(cls.agents_id == aid).first()

@classmethod
def set_status_log(cls, status, change_agent=None, agent_id=None, source=None, status_type=None):
    if agent_id:
        sl = Session.query(cls).filter(cls.agents_id == agent_id).first()
        sl.modify_stamp = func.now()
        sl.source = source
        if sl.status:
            sl.previous_status = sl.status
            sl.data[str(datetime.datetime.now())] = [{"status": sl.status, "change_agent": change_agent, "source": source}]
        sl.status = status
        sl.change_agents_id = change_agent
        sl.status_type = status_type
        transaction.commit()
```

Maybe I'm just over looking something simple, but this boggles my mind... When I do the same thing in my python shell, it works...
`merge_agent_log` is a SQLAlchemy object.

- What possible could possibly cause this cause this?
- Am I missing something? I have be having at this for two days...
- Is there in any case an entry to a dict would fail using `data["foo"] = "bar"`?

Comment: Please paste the definition of `merge_agent_log` class.

Comment: If  `merge_agent_log.data` is really a `dict` (not a dict-like nor some exotic dict subclass) there's no reason it should not set your key/value... "assuming that it is going into the else block", of course.

Comment: Curiosity! Try: merge_agent_log.data[now].append({"status": dup_agent_log.status, "change_agent": dup_agent_log.change_agent, "source": dup_agent_log.source})

Comment: @user3378649 nope, doesn't work :/... I updated the question with the `AgentStatusLog` class..

Comment: As I supposed, no dict has failed here - check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No dict has failed here, it just that you created more than one dict and did not realize it.

Let's analyze `merge_agent_log.data[now] = something` closely: first the property getter is called. It reads `_data` and creates a new dict with `json.loads`. Then you modify this new dict, adding `something` for key `now`.

But you do not modify `_data`!

So the next time you call the property getter with `merge_agent_log.data`, you read the same string from `_data` and create another dict with the same contents you did before.

Try this:

```
data = merge_agent_log.data
data[now] = something
merge_agent_log.data = data  # calls property setter, which modifies _data
```